# Web scraping of research paper on IEEE Xplore website using BeautifulSoup and request Python libraries

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, urllib

I am trying to scrape the Abstract of the research paper on IEEE Xplore website, [link :](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8480057). For this I used urllib library and Beautifulsoup in Python(3.10.9).  Below is the code i have used:

`

```
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    url = 'https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8480057'

    headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

    req = Request(url, headers=headers)
    response = urlopen(req, timeout=10)
    html_text = response.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
    # Find the element containing the abstract
    abstract_element = soup.find("div", class_="u-pb-1")
    # Extract the text from the abstract element
    abstract = abstract_element.text.strip()
    # Print the abstract
    print(abstract)
```

`

[Here i have attached the screenshot of html part having Abstract.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKgci.png)

> I am getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' for abstract.

I got the value of soup. But I don't know how to get the Abstract text. I am new to web scraping. I have tried a lot but didn't able to solve it.
Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: when using `requests` , first check if you are really getting the html content you see on the browser. for example, if you write the received HTML to a file and then open that html file in the browser, you will notice the problem. write content to file `with open("received_page.html","w") as fh:
    fh.write(str(soup))` , this is the reason that people use selenium for data extraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it's actually possible to get the abstract without the need for Selenium. I generally use the `requests` library and css selectors in BeautifulSoup and that's what I did here:

```
import requests
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
```

and then simply:

```
print(soup.select_one('meta[property="og:description"]')['content'])
```

The output should be the abstract.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This worked for me. I am a beginner and still learning about web scraping. Could you please explain me about >'('meta[property="og:description"]')['content']')'. Like how to know that this has to be used?

Comment: The above code doesn't give abstract in proper format for another [link] ( https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9800203). Could you please once more help me.

Comment: @DeveshS In the case of the 2nd document, the text of the abstract is, for some reason, sprinkled with non-well-formed xml tags, which don't render on the web page but do render on `print`. It's possible to extract the abstract from there by using a library such as lxml (although that probably should be presented in a separate question, per SO policy). But it's important that you realize that things like this are **very** likely to happen with web scraping. Page structures are changed frequently and sometimes radically, and you'll always have to play catch up with them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have cleaned the text with regex.

Comment: @DeveshS As many people before me said, [it's not a good idea to parse xml with regex....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454?ref=blog.codinghorror.com#1732454). In any case, if we're done, please don't forget to accept the answer.